# How do I add a JavaScript file from a module?

Tags: javascript

```
$form['set_end_date'] = array (
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('set end date'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Fetch'),
  '#button_type' => 'primary',
);
return $form;
```

How do I add a JavaScript file from a module?

Comment: are you using drupal 7 or 8?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add the js in libraries.yml, like

```
dirty_forms:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/jquery.dirtyforms.js:{}
dirty_forms_ckeditor:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/jquery.dirtyforms.ckeditor.js:{}
```

and then include in the form via

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'dirty_forms/dirty_forms';
```